# How to get mime name from array struct

Tags: c#

I have `MimeVideo` struct and use it in list to store mime video file.  What I'm trying to to is to get value of `mimefile` name by `Ext` to store it in `MediaTypeHeaderValue`. How to do that?

```
struct MimeVideo
{
    private readonly string _ext;
    private readonly string _file;
    public MimeVideo(string ext, string file)
    {
        this._ext = ext;
        this._file = file;
    }
    public string Ext { get { return _ext; } }
    public string File { get { return _file; } }

}
static readonly IList<MimeVideo> MimeNames = new ReadOnlyCollection<MimeVideo>
(new[] {
     new MimeVideo (".mp4", "video/mp4"),
     new MimeVideo (".ogg", "application/ogg"),
     new MimeVideo (".ogv", "video/ogg"),
     new MimeVideo (".webm", "video/webm")
});

private static MediaTypeHeaderValue GetMimeNameFromExt(string ext)
{
    string name ;
     get the name of file using ext 
    if (MimeNames // get filename by using ext)
        return new MediaTypeHeaderValue(name );
    else
        return new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private static MediaTypeHeaderValue GetMimeNameFromExt(string ext)
{
   MimeVideo first = MimeNames
      .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Ext.Equals(ext, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
   if(first == null) 
       return new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
   else
       return new MediaTypeHeaderValue(first.File);
}
```

or with `Where` + `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
private static MediaTypeHeaderValue GetMimeNameFromExt(string ext)
{
    return MimeNames
        .Where(m => m.Ext.Equals(ext, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        .Select(m => new MediaTypeHeaderValue(m.File))
        .DefaultIfEmpty(new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet))
        .First();
}
```

You haven't shown how you get the extension, i suggest usig `System.IO.Path.GetExtension`. I would also use a `Dictionary<string, MimeVideo>` instead.

Comment: Seems missing `.Select(m => new MediaTypeHeaderValue(m.Ext))`.